# IPython Notebooks - highlight cells which are awaiting execution?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

We are experimenting with iPython and so far are quite impressed.  However, there is a slight irritation that if you modify code in an input cell and click elsewhere it can appear to have executed (there is output!) but it has not been return.

What would be really nice is if there was a way that cell background colour changed if it has not been executed (or executed since the last change).  Has anyone tried to do this?   I guess if you take this to the extreme you might also highlight cells which are out of order - where there is a risk it no longer 'makes sense' if run top to bottom.

Comment: We investigated this, and it turns out to be harder and more confusing than it sounds - see the discussion at https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/4362